# How to know that current screen is Full-screen mode in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, window, screen, foreground

How can I know that current screen is Full-screen mode in Android?

I'm making a service that notifies some message through status bar.

But It has a problem when status bar is hide.

So I want to know that whether status bar is on the screen or not.

I tried to find out the way. But I don't know how to know that.

Please help me from this problem ;)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

> How can I know that current screen is Full-screen mode in Android?

You can't, sorry.